# Python Pika and RabbitMQ Connecting to Publish

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

Trying to send data into a RabbitMQ queue using Python.

I haven't configured the server but it is running for other processes. I have a working login and can access the web output without problem.

The example code RabbitMQ gives for python uses Pika:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='Test')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

This runs and kicks me off with:

```
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

Not a lot to go on but safe assumption is a login issue because the example code doesn't have any login info.

So I added it.

```
import pika
import sys
try:

    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('username', 'password')


    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
                                           xxxxx,
                                           'virtualhostnamehere',
                                           credentials,))

    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='Test')

    channel.basic_publish(exchange='amq.direct',
                          body='Hello World!')
    print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print e
```

It seems to hang around for a good few minutes before giving me:

```
<class 'pika.exceptions.IncompatibleProtocolError'>
```

The server is running other services fine but I can't seem to pinpoint what I've done wrong.

The login is correct. The vhost name is correct. The host is correct. the exchange name is correct.

Would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Update:

I've tried using URLParameters as well with the same results.

```
parameters = pika.URLParameters('amqp://username:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/notmyvhostname')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
```

Comment: Which port and username are you using?

Comment: I've replaced the login with "username" and "password" and the port as xxxxx.

Comment: But I guess the port doesn't change anything. It's port 15672 and the login is the same as I used to get on the browser output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I guess the port doesn't change anything. It's port 15672 and the
>   login is the same as I used to get on the browser output.

Use port 5672 - or whichever default port you have setup for AMQP listener. Port 15672 is for web UI access, which is done over HTTP, hence the incompatible protocol error

Comment: I've tried three different libs and some interesting approaches to the HTTP API and changing the port did it. Well it still won't write the channel is being closed but it's connecting at least. Thanks for that feeling stupid I didn't think of it sooner.

Comment: Np - happens to all of us ;)